# Safely delete Windows-like folders in Ubuntu account?

Tags: ubuntu

I installed a ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso as a VirtualBox VM.  The very first account that was automatically created was an administrator account.  It contained the following folders, all empty with one exception:

```
~/Desktop/
~/Documents/
~/Downloads/
~/Music/
~/Pictures/
~/Public/
~/Templates/
~/Videos/
```

The only exception is `~/Desktop/.inpurc`, which was identical to `~/.inpurc`, so I probably copied it in by accident.

When I created a nonadministrator account, it didn't have any of those folders.  I don't find those folders to be useful for the way I normally organize my files.  Since they were put there by default, can I safely delete them?

**Afternote:** It turns out that the nonadministrator account didn't have those folders because I `su`d into that account rather than logging in from the login screen.  When I did the latter, the nonadministraor account contained these Windows-like folders.  It would be nice to know whether I can safely remove them without upsetting Ubuntu apps.

Comment: If you don't want to standard desktop environment (and those folders are part of that), you can install Ubuntu Server. Then when installed, you can add the program packages you want, for example a simple window manager if you want graphics, for example `fluxbox`. - Otherwise, the standard desktop folders do not occupy much drive space, and you can simply ignore them and use custom locations for your files, for example in a separate 'data' partition. (Beware that some desktop tools may 'want to' write to those folders, but you **dare try to remove them** with a test user account.)

Comment: I actually wanted to remove them not for the space but the cognitive noise.  Based on what you described, I'll avoid the risk and create a folder "myStf" as a peer to those.  Thanks!  Did you want to post your comment as the answer?

Comment: OK, I made it into an answer. Good luck with your custom folder :-)

Comment: @sudodus: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ubuntu Server

If you don't want the standard desktop environment (and those folders are part of that), you can install Ubuntu Server. Then when installed, you can add the program packages you want, for example a simple window manager if you want graphics, for example `fluxbox`.

### Ubuntu Desktop

Otherwise, the standard desktop folders do not occupy much drive space, and you can simply ignore them and use custom locations for your files, for example in a separate 'data' partition. (I have the root partition in an SSD and a data partition in a big HDD, and it works well for me.)

Beware that some desktop tools may 'want to' write to those folders, but ***you dare try to remove them** with a **test** user account*. It will not damage your main user account, and you may find that it works well.